# Increase the speed at which the 'delete' key deletes things on OSX?

Tags: macos

I want to hold the 'delete' key and delete characters more quickly than OSX Mavericks does by default. Something like Ubuntu, which delete really quickly. Any suggestions?!

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Under System Preferences, click Keyboard, and adjust the "Key Repeat" speed (see below). Tested in Word and it does affect how quickly the delete key deletes characters when held down.

[image]

Alternatively, in the terminal you can enter

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain KeyRepeat -int 0
```

which is the fastest setting. The fastest exposed by System Preferences is 2 (log out and back in to see changes).
See here: [Mac OSX Hints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090823193018149)

Additionally,

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain InitialKeyRepeat -int 15
```

can be used to change the delay before the repeat starts (default is 15).

For a graphical solution, see keyremap4macbook, detailed [here](http://continentalroast.blogspot.com/2011/08/macos-fast-key-repeat.html).

Answer (score 12):

You can also hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key while pressing delete. This deletes whole words instead of characters. Similar functionality to holding <kbd>Control</kbd> while pressing backspace in windows.

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work inside the terminal on my mac.  Option+arrow-keys moves the cursor a word a time, but option+delete doesn't delete a word a time.  Oddly, it does inside this editor window.

Comment: Great for other apps but doesn't work in Terminal.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>esc</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> should work on Mac terminal

Comment: The answer is just too short.

Comment: But correct! Though only works for one word at a time. You have to repeat pressing `esc`. Hopefully my answer is not too short.