# How to increase the keyboard repeat rate on MacOS 10.15.6?

Tags: macos, keyboard, repeat-rate

This is driving me crazy.

I know I can set it in System Preference, but it is not fast enough.

I also tried `defaults write -g KeyRepeat -int 1`, but it seems that the minimum value is just 1, and it is still too slow.

"keyremap4macbook" doesn't work.

I also tried Karabiner-Elements, but it doesn't have this functionality at all: https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/help/how-to/key-repeat/

Could someone teach me please！
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Is this considered too slow?](https://streamable.com/tw98wc) Also, after changing the default writes in terminal, did you log out and log back in?

Comment: @DrZoo The speed in your screen record is good. How to achieve that? And yes I did log out and log back in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase the speed at which the 'delete' key deletes things on OSX?](https://superuser.com/questions/677665/increase-the-speed-at-which-the-delete-key-deletes-things-on-osx)

Comment: Doesn't work. I found that the main reason is that the command `defaults write NSGlobalDomain KeyRepeat -int 0` doesn't work at all. I logged out and back in, and I can see the value is 0 in terminal, but the speed just doesn't change. @Tetsujin

Comment: @Tetsujin I see, the commands are already ineffective. Really regret to switch from Windows to this stupid MacOs. Thanks anyway! https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259820/macos-sierra-breaks-a-lot-of-terminal-defaults-write-commands-tap-to-click-fo

Comment: Assume that knocking macOS on a Mac user site, populated by people for whom Windows is anathema is likely the wrong way to win friends or get help. Instead, how about thinking about it from another angle -  why not ask about what you actually are trying to achieve rather than how you think you might achieve it? I honestly can't think of many occasions I need a faster repeat rate, so I've probably figured out a better way to do a lot of the tasks which might otherwise need a high repeat rate.

Comment: BTW, I just set mine to 1 to test [zero doesn't work any more, anything higher still works just fine] & it's considerably faster than the video clip linked above. Too fast for me, unless you're trying to clear back to 'empty' as you over-delete past where you needed far too easily. Having said that, if you want to delete a whole line, I'm sure it's way faster to triple-click & hit delete once. [Harking back to my last comment about "what you're trying to achieve"]

Comment: @Tetsujin Sorry, didn't mean to offend anyone. But I tried value 1 for many times, it doesn't work. And based on the link I posted above, the command itself is no longer effective.

Comment: Precisely what was your input? Based on my linked question, not any other reference [your link had no connection to this issue], it should be `defaults write NSGlobalDomain KeyRepeat -int 1` [I'm not certain whether `-g` is exactly equal to `NSGlobalDomain` though it might be.]

Comment: @Tetsujin I tried everything. `defaults write NSGlobalDomain KeyRepeat -int 1`, `defaults write NSGlobalDomain KeyRepeat -int 0`, `defaults write -g KeyRepeat -int 1`, `defaults write -g KeyRepeat -int 0`, none of them works. The 2nd comment in my link says "Indeed, Terminal commands that once adjusted key repeat rates and mission control animation speeds no longer work either. ", which I think is the reason. Now if I want to erase 100 letters, it will cost 1 minute.

Comment: ..and you are relogging between each test? These defaults will only be read when you login to your account. What OS are you on? I can test this works perfectly up to Mojave, but i can't test Catalina. [I have some feelers out for people to test for me on 10.15, waiting for them to get back to me] I still think if you want to erase a whole line, or 100+ chars, there are much better methods.

Comment: Yes I did logged out and back in every time. My OS is Catalina 10.15.6 (19G2021). Thanks for your help! Please inform me when you get feedback from your friends. @Tetsujin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was because I turned on the "Slow Key" functionality as shown below:

[image]

After I turned it off, the key repeat rate works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

> In order to achieve the delete speed shown in the comment, I have my
> keyboard settings set to the following:

[image]

> The values I have set for `InitialKeyRepeat` and `KeyRepeat` are the following:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for me... It seems that the commands conflict with the System preference setting. I set "Key Repeat" in System preference to be the fastest, then entered the 2 commands, then restarted the computer. Then the 2 values are 10 and 1 respectively, which I saw in the terminal, but the actually speed didn't change at all, as slow as hell. And I found the System preference had been reset, being placed in the middle, not the fastest. Then I set it to fastest again, after which I found the 2 values were reset to 68 and 2 respectively. It really drove me crazy...

Comment: This doesn't tell anyone how to set it, only how to read the values. Also, pictures of terminal windows cannot be searched. Text is better.